# How to optimize MySQL queries with many combinations of where conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a MySQL table like this, and I want to create indexes that make all queries to the table run fast. The difficult thing is that there are many possible combinations of `where` conditions, and that the size of table is large (about 6M rows).

```
Table name: items    

id: PKEY
item_id: int (the id of items)
category_1: int
category_2: int
.
.
.
category_10: int
release_date: date
sort_score: decimal
```

`item_id` is not unique because an item can have several numbers of `category_x` .

An example of queries to this table is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) FROM items WHERE category_1 IN (1, 2) AND category_5 IN (3, 4), AND release_date > '2019-01-01' ORDER BY sort_score
```

And another query maybe:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) FROM items WHERE category_3 IN (1, 2) AND category_4 IN (3, 4), AND category_8 IN (5) ORDER BY sort_score
```

If I want to optimize **all** the combinations of where conditions , do I have to make a huge number of composite indexes of the column combinations? (like `ADD INDEX idx1_3_5(category_1, category_3, category_5)`)

Or is it good to create 10 tables which have data of category_1~10, and execute many `INNER JOIN` in the queries?

Or, is it difficult to optimize this kind of queries in MySQL, and should I use other middlewares , such as Elasticsearch ?

Comment: So to be clear - a single item may have multiple category_1 values, and if so you have two rows in this table, one with each of the possible combinations? That sounds inefficient, and probably better to include a many to many ItemCategory(ItemID,CategoryID) table.

Comment: Apart from that, if you stick to your current structure, it is probably going to work to create an index on each category, and let the query optimiser worry about how it is going to merge the indexes based on your query.

Comment: BTW - is this mysql or postgressql. You have tagged both but it can only be one or the other.

Comment: Yes I have two records when an item has multiple category_1 values.

Comment: If I create an index on each category, does MySQL optimiser use multiple single indexes at the same time? I thought it can use only an index at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, this is MySQL.

Comment: Your queries are not valid SQL.   You are sorting by a column not mentioned in the `distinct`.  This should be returning an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the file (it is not a table) is not at all Normalised.  Therefore no amount indices on combinations of fields will help the queries.

Second, MySQL is (a) not compliant with the SQL requirement, and (b) it does not have a Server Architecture or the features of one.

- Such a Statistics, which is used by a genuine Query Optimiser, which commercial SQL platforms have.  The "single index" issue you raise in the comments does not apply.

Therefore, while we can fix up the table, etc, you may never obtain the performance that you seek from the freeware.

- Eg. in the commercial world, 6M rows is nothing, we worry when we get to a billion rows.
- Eg. Statistics is automatic, we have to tweak it only when necessary: an un-normalised table or billions of rows.

> Or ... should I use other middlewares , such as Elasticsearch ?

It depends on the use of genuine SQL vs MySQL, and the middleware.

- If you fix up the file and make a set of Relational tables, the queries are then quite simple, and fast.  It does not justify a middleware search engine (that builds a data cube on the client system).
- If they are not fast on MySQL, then the first recommendation would be to get a commercial SQL platform instead of the freeware.
- The last option, the very last, is to stick to the freeware and add a big fat middleware search engine to compensate.

> Or is it good to create 10 tables which have data of category_1~10, and execute many INNER JOIN in the queries?

Yes.  JOINs are quite ordinary in SQL.  Contrary to popular mythology, a normalised database, which means many more tables than an un-normalised one, causes fewer JOINs, not more JOINs.

So, yes, Normalise that beast.  Ten tables is the starting perception, still not at all Normalised.  One table for each of the following would be a step in the direction of Normalised:

1. Item
   `Item_id` will be unique.
2. Category
   This is not `category-1`, etc, but each of the values that are in `category_1`, etc.  You must not have multiple values in a single column, it breaks 1NF.  Such values will be (a) Atomic, and (b) unique.  The *Relational Model* demands that the rows are unique.
3. The meaning of `category_1`, etc in `Item` is not given.  (If you provide some example data, I can improve the accuracy of the data model.)  Obviously it is not [2].
   .
   If it is a Priority (1..10), or something similar, that the users have chosen or voted on, this table will be a table that supplies the many-to-many relationship between `Item` and `Category`, with a `Priority` for each row.
   .
   Let's call it Poll.  The relevant Predicates would be something like:

   ```
   Each Poll is 1 Item
   Each Poll is 1 Priority
   Each Poll is 1 Category
   ```
4. Likewise, `sort_score` is not explained.  If it is even remotely what it appears to be, you will not need it.  Because it is a **Derived Value**.  That you should compute on the fly: once the tables are Normalised, the SQL required to compute this is straight-forward.  Not one that you compute-and-store every 5 minutes or every 10 seconds.

### The Relational Model

The above maintains the scope of just answering your question, without pointing out the difficulties in your file.  Noting the `Relational Database` tag, this section deals with the Relational errors.

1. The `Record ID` field (`item_id` or `category_id` is yours) is prohibited in the *Relational Model*.  It is a physical pointer to a record, which is explicitly the very thing that the *RM* overcomes, and that is required to be overcome if one wishes to obtain the benefits of the *RM*, such as ease of queries, and simple, straight-forward SQL code.

   Conversely, the `Record ID` is always one additional column and one additional index, and the SQL code required for navigation becomes complex (and buggy) very quickly.  You will have enough difficulty with the code as it is, I doubt you would want the added complexity.

   Therefore, get rid of the `Record ID` fields.
2. The *Relational Model* requires that the Keys are "made up from the data".  That means something from the logical row, that the users use.  Usually they know precisely what identifies their data, such as a short name.

   - It is not manufactured by the system, such as a `RecordID` field which is a `GUID` or `AUTOINCREMENT`, which the user does not see.  Such fields are physical pointers to records, not Keys to logical rows.  Such fields are pre-Relational, pre-DBMS, 1960's Record Filing Systems, the very thing that *RM* superseded.  But they are heavily promoted and marketed as "relational.

#### Relational Data Model • Initial

Looks like this.

[image: TaichiTA]

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners.

#### Relational Data Model • Improved

Ternary relations (aka three-way JOINs) are known to be a problem, indicating that further Normalisation is required.  Codd teaches that every ternary relation can be reduced to two binary relations.

In your case, perhaps a Item has certain, not all, Categories.  The above implements Polls of Items allowing all Categories for each Item, which is typical error in a ternary relation, which is why it requires further Normalisation.  It is also the classic error in every RFS file.

The corrected model would therefore be to establish the Categories for each Item first as ItemCategory, your "item can have several numbers of category_x". And then to allow Polls on that constrained ItemCategory.  Note, this level of constraining data is not possible in 1960' Record Filing Systems, in which the "key" is a fabricated `id` field:

[image: TaichiTA2]

```
Each ItemCategory is 1 Item
Each ItemCategory is 1 Category
Each Poll is 1 Priority
Each Poll is 1 ItemCategory
```

- Your indices are now simple and straight-forward, no additional indices are required.
- Likewise your query code will now be simple and straight-forward, and far less prone to bugs.
- Please make sure that you learn about Subqueries.  The Poll table supports any type of pivoting that may be required.

---

Comment: @Taichi.  1) I improved the wordings, and hopefully the clarity.  2) If you provide some example data values (meaningful values, not numbers), I can improve the accuracy of the data model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
- category_1,2,3,... are actually *independent* int columns, such as `country_id, region_id, company_id, department_id, floor_id,...`. So there are no relations among them such as Priority. I'm developing a search system of items. Each column (such as department_id, floor_id,...) Each id can be about 1~100.

Comment: - `sort_score` is not a derived value. It is calculated for each item in another system, and inserted into this DB. (example value: `0.12`, `1.341`,...)
So I think I need an index on this column to sort the result using `sorted_score` .

Comment: The reason why I created this one large `items` table is that I thought I can search them faster if the data are aggregated into one table.
I thought it will take long time to execute many (5, 6, .. or 10) `INNER JOIN`s to search items by many `category_n` columns.

Comment: @Taichi. You are welcome! 0) `Priority` & `Poll` was a guess, the data model was a demonstration.  1) one large `items` table will be (a) not faster, (b) a disaster to maintain, even if it is a DW/DSS/OLAP system. 2) the fastest access known to science is **Relational**, it is also the smallest database (overall) and easiest to manage. 3) If you give me all your Dimensions, what they mean (please, minus the `ids` because they cripple the modelling exercise), I will give you the fastest database.  Update your Question with the details.

Comment: 4) If you have a genuine SQL platform, `JOINs` are not an issue.  5) `sort_score` you need an index only if it is used as a search criteria. There is no need to "sort" it if it comes in from another system.

Comment: 2) More.  For performance, you need to spread the query load.  One large table guarantees that every query will have to contend against every other query, in one table.

Answer (score 1):

It is messy to optimize such queries against such a table.  Moving the categories off to other tables would only make it slower.

Here's a partial solution...  Identify the categories that are *likely* to be tested with

1. `=`
2. `IN`
3. a range, such as your example `release_date > '2019-01-01'`

Then devise a few indexes (perhaps no more than a dozen) that have, say, 3-4 columns.  Those columns should be ones that are often tested together.  Order the columns in the indexes based on the list above.  It is quite fine to have multiple `=` columns (first), but don't include more than one 'range' (last).

Keep in mind that the order of tests in `WHERE` does not matter, but the order of the columns in an `INDEX` does.